# How to set multiple default constraint to multiple columns at once in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, constraints, alter-table, default-constraint

Is there a way to alter table to set multiple default constraints at once in MySQL?

This is what I tried

```
ALTER TABLE test00.tbl_00 ALTER card_flg_visa,card_flg_jcb SET DEFAULT (0, 1);
```

The following error occured

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', card_flg_jcb SET DEFAULT (0, 1)' at line 1

Answer (score 3):

You can write this as one query but you have to alter each column separately:

```
ALTER TABLE test00.tbl_00 
    ALTER card_flg_visa SET DEFAULT 0,
    ALTER card_flg_jcb SET DEFAULT 1;
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2b4c8029138263c7d6836ae29a383488)